Multiple workspaces created on Jenkins build nodes even when number of executors set to 1
I have a Jenkins set up with a single server (obviously) and two build nodes on two computers.
I have a job that is very resource intensive and need to ensure that only one job is ever running at a time on either of the build nodes. But I would like to be able to utilize both build nodes concurrently.
Each build node is set to have a single executor.
If I set the job to allow concurrent builds I see multiple workspaces on each build node (even though I only allow a single executor on each build node.) If I don't allow concurrent jobs then I only ever see one job running on a single build node at any given time (as expected.)
I am probably missing something but I would expect that allowing concurrent builds, while having only a single executor on each node would do what I want. Any ideas?
Server and nodes are on Windows 10. Jenkins version 2.452.3
